# Dual external monitors (different resolutions) for laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I've purchased a [Dell XPS 16](http://www.dell.com/us/en/home/notebooks/laptop-studio-xps-16/pd.aspx?refid=laptop-studio-xps-16&s=dhs&cs=19&~ck=mn)  as a desktop replacement which supports up to 1920x1080 resolution on the laptop's screen.  I have two external monitors that I would like to use.  One is 1920x1200 and the other is 1600x1200.  Both support both DVI and VGA, though I'd prefer DVI of course.

Unfortunately, the laptop only has one VGA port for an external display.

I've already checked out [Maxtor DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go), but this will not work for me because it requires both monitors to use the same resolution.  I don't want to squish my 1920x1200 monitor down to 1600x1200.

I also looked at the [Targus ACP60US](http://www.targus.com/us/product_details.aspx?sku=ACP60US), but its max resolution is 1600x1200 (and there's no clear indication of whether or not it will actually support two monitors... I've seen other docking stations that support only 1 monitor and just have both inputs for you to choose from).

I would hate to have to give up my 21".

Can someone suggest a solution for me?

**EDIT:** Graphics card is an ATI Mobility RADEON HD 3670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Dells's specs](http://www.dell.com/us/en/home/notebooks/laptop-studio-xps-16/pd.aspx?refid=laptop-studio-xps-16&s=dhs&cs=19&~ck=mn) your laptop has an HDMI as well as a Display Port output as well.  HDMI->DVI adapters are very cheap and DispalyPort->DVI adapters aren't that expensive as well.  So you can easily hook up both monitors to your laptop.  However, most likely at least, the laptop can only drive two monitors at a time so with both monitors enabled, the laptop screen will be off.

See these adapters at MonoPrice for example:

[HDMI->DVI](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041902&p_id=2080&seq=1&format=2)

[DisplayPort->DVI](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042801&p_id=4827&seq=1&format=2)

Comment: that might be a newer model, as it lists a Radeon HD 4670 as graphics card, the display port is definitely new ... either way, both cards can only drive 2 displays, if Mike wants to use 2 monitors plus the laptop display, there's no way around an external graphics card.

Comment: The DisplayPort->DVI adapter says it only supports up to 1920x1080 (I need 1200 vertical).  HDMI->DVI + using the VGA port directly should work, though.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using that exact DisplayPort->DVI adapter at 1920x1200 without issue on my Dell E6500.

Answer (score 1):

why not use the Targus ACP60US for the 1600x1200 monitor and the 1920x1200 monitor on the VGA port of the Laptop, the Mobility Radeon HD3670 is capable of that resolution over a VGA connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your other option for driving the second monitor (if the laptop won't do it, or won't do it with it's own screen active is to get a USB video adapter.

Monoprice has some very good ones, that will support up to 1920x1200 or 2048x1152  for around $50.  the PID (if it has not changed) is 6038

I'm using a pair (one at home, one at work) to run a 'triple mon' setup with a macbook pro.  the first external monitor is off the 'thunderbolt (mini-displayport) and the second external monitor is off the USB adapter.

The performance of the usb adaptor is not up to what you would need for gaming, but for most desktop uses, including watching video, or doing google hangouts, it works just fine.